# Overlapping columns after resizing in Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Why in the following Bootstrap 3.0 sample the right panel hides completely the form when I reduce the width of the browser?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <h2>Product selection</h2>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <hr />
    <form action="/Store" class="form-horizontal" id="productForm" method="post" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Quantity">Quantity</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity" onchange="this.form.submit();" type="text" value="1" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input name="nextButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Next" />
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Your Options</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p style="line-height: 200%">
                <a href="#">Other ways to buy</a><br/>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a live test of what happens:

http://www.bootply.com/R4FsSHI4af

To reproduce it you need simply to reduce the width of the browser window.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing `col-sm-9` with `col-md-3`. Just use one size, for example `col-md-9` and `col-md-3`.

Comment: Thanks, I miss your eagle eye!

Answer (score 0):

Use this structure instead :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <!-- Panel -->
    </div>
</div>
```

As you're mixing `col-sm-9` and `col-md-3`, you've got :

- a 12-12 pattern on small devices
- a 9-12 pattern on medium devices : overlap
- a 9-3 pattern on large and extra large devices